# Implement a product discount based on a dynamic value

Tags: 7, entities, commerce, rules

I am new to Drupal CMS and i would like to add a "discount field" on my product so when i am adding/updating a product, i can set an "integer value" inside this "discount field" and so the "product price" will be discounted based on the "value" of this field.

Example:

I want to create a product "A" with original price of "120$", now while adding this product to my store, i want to add the value of "20" inside the "discount field" and so the price will be displayed for users as: (120$ x 20%) = 96$

Thank you,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had similar question a while ago...
this involve creation of 4 separate discount Rules via Commerce Discount UI and then modifying each created discount rule via Rules UI.

Have a look to this answer here:
[Dynamic Discount using taxonomy term reference field to define specific discount value](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/211502/dynamic-discount-using-taxonomy-term-reference-field-to-define-specific-discount)

Post back if you need any help,

Comment: Thank you for the help, i will take a look to the link and revert back with any question

Comment: Actually the link you provided is exactly what i am looking for... i can say now my problem has been solved... cheers mate

Comment: Well, glad i was able to help you... Anytime ! Cheers!